# How to Magento 2 Last ordered id and how to get last 2 orders details

Tags: magento2, order-email

I have tried to show last 2 ordered details with that particular id. But there is only one last order details are showing.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Please update your code and explain the question more.

Comment: <div class="block-title no-display"
         data-bind="css: {'no-display': !lastOrderedItems().items || lastOrderedItems().items.length === 0}">
        <strong id="block-reorder-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Recently Ordered') ?></strong>
    </div>
<div class="block-content no-display"
         data-bind="css: {'no-display': !lastOrderedItems().items || lastOrderedItems().items.length === 0}"
         aria-labelledby="block-reorder-heading">
</div>

Comment: I need lastorder only. Which is should be included in sidebar.php